# JS Regex match word starting with character but ignore if it's double

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regular exp :: `/(?:^|\W)\£(\w+)(?!\w)/g`

This is meant to match words following the character `£` . ie; if you type `Something £here` it will match `£here` .

However, if you type `££here` I don't want it to be matched, however, i'm unsure how to match `£` starting but ignore if it's `££`.

Is there guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: What **exactly** is `here`? A word, decimal, anything? for example would `£$` be valid? Generally regexes work better at defining what you **want**. They get cliunky at defining what you don't want

Answer (score 1):

You can add `£` to `\W`:

```
/(?:^|[^\w£])£(\w+)/g
```

Actually, `(?!\w)` is redundant here (as after a word char, there is no more word chars) and you can remove it safely.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UnmrK9/1). *Details*:

- `(?:^|[^\w£])` - start of string or any single char other than a word and  a `£` char
- `£` - a literal char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you also don't want to match `$£here`

```
(?<!\S)£(\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `£` Match literally
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word characters in *group 1*

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTvktn/1).

---

If a lookbehind is not supported:

```
(?:^|\s)£(\w+)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yst8Gt/1).